# How come my trash isn't being taken out?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I have an complex and extensive AE system set up. In this system, I have two barrels (of cobblestone) connected to my AE network via storage buses. These buses are set at a priority level of 64.  MY AE Drive is set at priority level 1. This setup tells my network to store cobblestone first in the barrels, and then if there is no room to instead store it in the drive.

I have decided I do not want more cobblestone than I have stored, so I connected a wooden chest to a void chest via hopper, and then setup a third storage bus to this wooden chest. I configured the storage bus to only store cobblestone, and set it a priority level of 63.  This as I understand it will make the system first check the barrels, and then if they are full, to then store the cobblestone into the chest.

My problem is that the AE system will not store excess cobblestone in the chest, and insteaed continues to store it in my drives. Why is this not working as intended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No matter what priority level you have it will check to see if that item is already in a drive and insert it. Take all the Cobblestone out of your disk drives and try again.  On a side note you could maybe use the cobblestone in an ME Condenser. 
[This Link Will Prove To Be A Big Help As Well](http://ae-mod.info/Miscellaneous-Tips/)  CASE 5 is what your problem is.

Comment: where did you find the link to that particular page on the site, I'm often going through the AE site and I've never seen a link to the tips page.

Comment: [Under ME Drive Section. I figured that your disks would be stored there. HERE](http://ae-mod.info/ME-Drive/)

Comment: Thanks, and I knew about drives long before the website, so I never actually looked at that particular page. awesome.